# <br> not working within an #each loop in a handlebars html template file

Tags: html, css, handlebars.js

Following is the code from a .hbs file to create multiple tables one after another.
At the end there are two `<br>` tags to ensure two line breaks between the different tables created

```
{{#each container}}
    <div>
      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered" style="margin-left:0px;float: left;align:left;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="color:rgb(68, 67, 67);font-weight: normal;">...</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {{#each variable}}
            <tr>
              <td style="border:none;">...</td>                  
            </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br><br>
{{/each}}
```

But after using this hbs to create an html page, the two line breaks are not visible. How to get this working?

Comment: try placing `<br>` inside the `</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `br` use inline style and add `margin-bottom`

```
     {{#each container}}
            <div style:"margin-bottom:30px;">
              <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered" style="margin-

left:0px;float: left;align:left;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="color:rgb(68, 67, 67);font-weight: normal;">...</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {{#each variable}}
                <tr>


        <td style="border:none;">...</td>                  
            </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `line-height` of `<br>` element and nothing to do with Handlebars. You could write inline style to handle the space and may use one 
 instead of two.

```
<br style="line-height: 5rem;" />
```

Hope this helps.